# Windows equivalent command for retraining inception

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, image-recognition

I have been successfully executing the tensorflow retraining example using docker toolbox according to following link https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0

However I was now interested in executing the same example in native windows environemnt as I am thinking tensorboard is easy to use that way. 
I was looking for the the windows equivalent of the following command entered in docker

## In Docker

python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \

--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \

--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \

--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \

--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \

--image_dir /tf_files/flower_photos

Kindly if some body could help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Provided that python/Tensorflow is installed correctly and that you are in the correct directory then that should work just fine. You might have to move it all onto one line though.

e.g. `python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py --bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks/` etc.